# pass user credentials to server from iphone application

Tags: ios4, nsurlconnection, iphone

Greetings,

I am making an `iphone` application to pass information between the application and the server database.
i have made an connection with the server database

```
NSURLRequest *reqURL = [NSURLRequest requestURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"address"]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:reqURL delegate:self];
```

Now i require to pass on the database name and the `username` and `password` to the database.
How can these credentials be passed on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the easiest way would be to simply append the username and password to the url:

```
NSString *surl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://my.server.net?username=%@&password=%@",username,password];
NSURLRequest *reqURL = [NSURLRequest requestURL: [NSURL URLWithString:surl]];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:reqURL delegate:self];
```

Comment: I believe it's not safe to do so since the password is exposed. POST is better than this, but still not secure. I'm also looking for a secured way to pass the info.

Comment: I agree @Xiao this isn't safe as the password is passed in the clear. A POST improves security but is still not safe. I was merely trying to answer the OP's question which seemed more syntactic than a question of security. That said the only truly secure way I can think of passing the password would be to encrypt it with a key that was stored on the client and on the server and pass the encrypted value instead.